# Parametric equations for path of particle around HALF of circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

I'm trying to determine the parametric equations of the path of a particle that travels the circle, *on a time interval of* $~0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$:

$$(x-5)^2 + (y-4)^2 = 100 $$

I have already solved the first two parts:

If that particle makes one full circles starting at the point (15,4) traveling *counterclockwise*:
$$x(t) = 5 + 10 \cos(t)~,  \qquad y(t) = 4 + 10 \sin(t)$$

If that particle makes one full circle starting at the point (5,14) traveling *clockwise*:
$$x(t) = 5 + 10 \sin(t) ~,  \qquad y(t) = 4 + 10 \cos(t)$$

However for the life of me I cannot figure out this one **without changing the bounds:**
if the particle makes one **half** of a circle starting at the point (15,4) traveling *clockwise*:
$$ x(t) = \text{?}   ~,  \qquad y(t) = \text{?}$$

Comment: What about using $\frac{t}{2}$ instead of $t$ as argument? ;-)

Comment: @zardos May the Gods smile upon you. That was it! And making sin negative.